# Query results which have a certain year on a date in string format

Tags: android, string, sqlite, date

I have my data stored on a field "date" with string format, I want to query the table to show the results who have a certain year that contains a specified year.

My problem is how to get the year from the string, what I currently have:

```
public Cursor getExpensesByYear () {

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EXPENSE + " WHERE strftime('%Y', date) = '2015'";

    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
    // String inputString = cursor.getString(5);

    // DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    // try {
    //    Date inputDate = dateFormat.parse(inputString);
    // } catch (ParseException e) {
    //   e.printStackTrace();
    // }

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return cursor;
}
```

It simply doesn't return any data.

Comment: See the [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sqlite/5252/data-types/18688/date-time-types).

Answer (score -1):

I follow your question but let me recommend you that, if you need to filter data as part of the core features, add a field with the year when you record the register. 
Once done, retrieve will be faster and direct.
Hope it helps.